# How to alter primary key constraint for 2 columns in same table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

In SQL Server, I already created a table called `tblDatabase` with some columns. I want to add a primary key on the two columns `DatabaseName` and `Servername`.

I tried to add:

```
ALTER TABLE tblDatabase ADD CONSTRAINT pk_DatabaseServer 
                            PRIMARY KEY (DatabaseName, ServerName)
```

in check constraints but I get pop up error that say

> *error validating constraint 'ck_tblDatabase'.*

Did I miss something?

I also have `ServerName` as PK in `tblServer` that already relationship with `tblDatabase`. Is that the reason why?

Comment: Does the table already have a primary key defined? Do you have data that is _duplicated_ across these two rows (if you do - your data prevents the primary key from being created - fix it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't enter this into the [**check** constraint dialogue box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188994%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). That only allows you to enter expressions for check constraints.

To create your primary key constraint you should just execute your TSQL `ALTER TABLE` script in a new query window.

To create this using the visual tools you would need to use the [indexes/keys dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187992%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) or in the table designer view select the two columns and choose "Set Primary Key" from the shortcut menu.

I would avoid this last approach for a composite PK however as AFAIK it gives you no way of controlling the order that the index keys will be defined in.